# differential code coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage

We're adding unit tests to previously untested code, as the need arises to modify that code.  It's difficult to get useful coverage metrics since the majority of code in any package is known to be untested.

Are there any tools available to measure **differential** code coverage, that is, the percent of code modified in a given changeset which was covered by a unit test?

Comment: for .net I've used NCoverCop http://sourceforge.net/projects/ncovercop/ which compares the xml output of ncover. Perhaps it could be adapted to your java output or there is a java equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Use [pycobertura](https://github.com/aconrad/pycobertura). It's a command-line tool to prevent code coverage regression by diffing two coverage reports. It tells you whether your new code is better or worse than the previous version, coverage-wise.

```
$ pycobertura diff ./master/coverage.xml ./myfeature/coverage.xml
```

It's language agnostic since it just relies on the Cobertura report (XML file) generated by your testing/coverage tool.

Pycobertura can also generate HTML reports which fit nicely in CI/CD tools such as Jenkins.

[image]

https://github.com/aconrad/pycobertura

Answer (score 1):

Continuous integration tools like Jenkins let you keep a history of test coverage and show you a graph that includes a coverage trend compared to previous builds. Example: [Cobertura Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin)

Comment: We're using Cobertura and Jenkins, and it's helpful to a point.  But we'd like to be able to see the coverage of new/changed code (i.e., 80% of delta code, compared to 1% of all code).  Being able to dig into individual packages/classes helps some, too, but only if you know which packages/classes have been modified.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gradle plugin that computes diff code coverage

https://github.com/form-com/diff-coverage-gradle

All you need is to provide diff file to the plugin or you can use `git diff` tool that is shown in [the example](https://github.com/form-com/diff-coverage-gradle#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into Sonar, really good tool to analyze entire application quality and coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did exactly that, using [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) and the [ConQAT](https://www.conqat.org/) framework for code analysis. The approach is as follows:

1. Load the source code from the baseline version and the head version (and potentially intermediary ones, if you also have done tests in-between)
2. Compare the program history method by method to determine where changes happened
3. Annotate coverage information to each tested revision
4. Search for methods that have not been covered since they last changed

There is also a [blog post](https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/take-control-of-your-testing-process/) containing a more detailed description including visualizations and more advanced topics like refactoring detection to only identify changes worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [diff-test-coverage](https://github.com/Connected-Information-systems/diff-test-coverage) for this. `diff-test-coverage` is a Node.js commandline tool which filters test coverage based on a (source control) diff.

It works by filtering the coverage report information, so it can report the coverage information for new code.

[image: diff-test-coverage]

It supports both Git and Mercurial and all common coverage report formats.